# What Ansible filter can I use on 'hostvars' to extract string?

Tags: ansible, filter

```yaml
"{{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['iosengineID'] }}"
```

value returns this

```json
{'msg': [['80000009045B575A5032333331303055565D']], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}
```

Which filter can I use extract or print or register the value?

```
80000009045B575A5032333331303055565D
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of *iosengineID* is a list with a single item that is a list

```yaml
iosengineID: [['80000009045B575A5032333331303055565D']]
```

What you want is the first item on the first list

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: iosengineID.0.0
```

gives

```yaml
  iosengineID.0.0: 80000009045B575A5032333331303055565D
```

Comment: Ah man that is way easier! Thanks.

Comment: @Andreas The way to say "thank you" on serverfault or on any other stackechange sites is to up-vote and/or accept (green tick) answers you find useful. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this crazy crazy filter on hostvars!!!!

```
"{{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['foundengineID'] | regex_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]','') | replace('msg','') | replace('failedFalsechangedFalse','') }}"
```

and then it writes this value so I can use it as a variable to write it in a file:

```
80000009045B575A5032333331303055565D
```

Comment: "_I had to use this crazy crazy filter on hostvars_", I don't think so and like to recommend to use the solution approach from the [here given answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1099227/448950).